# Mismatch with Angular material and Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

In get the following error after having done an npm install.

```
@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol
```

How can I install a the specific version of angular material so that I can realove this error.

My pacakage json looks like this

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
"angular2-recaptcha": "^0.6.0",
"angulartics2": "^3.3.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"chartjs": "^0.3.24",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"file-saver": "^1.3.3",
"financejs": "^4.1.0",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.9",
"ng2-currency-mask": "^4.4.1",
"ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^6.2.0",
"primeng": "^4.3.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"zone.js": "0.8.14"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a snapshot of the most recent release.

> A snapshot build with the latest changes from master is also
>   available. Note that this snapshot build should not be considered
>   stable and may break between releases.

- From the [material getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) website

Uninstall the snapshot builds for material and cdk:

```
npm uninstall --save angular/material2-builds angular/cdk-builds
```

Install the most recent stable

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

Also note:

You are using several npm packages labeled `ng2`, and these may require an older version and your more recent `primeng` requires a more recent material. You may not be able to use the older packages and newer primeng at the same time if they require different version of material (which may cause this error)